# asmx page is blank but WebService is working

Tags: web-services, asmx

I have a asmx WebService that works perfectly but returns a blank page when I browse to it in a browser.

When I browse to the `search.asmx` file I don't get the usual html format description of the service with the testing form that allows you to invoke the service. All I get is a completely blank page. (view source returns nothing).

This happens both on localhost (casini) and on the server (IIS 7.5).

Is there a way I can turn this on?

### My web.config looks like this:

```xml
  ...
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" enableKernelOutputCache="false"/>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
    ...
```

### My Service looks something like this:

```c#
...
[WebService(Namespace = "http://mydomain.edu/something")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]

[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class SearchService : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    public SearchService() {

    }

    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public SearchResponse Search(SearchFilter filter)
    {
...
```

## Update:

When I navigate to the wsdl `search.asmx?wsdl` I get an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Method Search can not be reflected.
>   ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting 'SearchResult'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There
>   was an error reflecting type 'SearchResponse'. --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting
>   property 'attributes'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException:
>   There was an error reflecting type 'USpaceDataAttributes'.
>   ---> System.NotSupportedException: Cannot serialize member USpaceDataAttributes.attributes of type
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[SimpleTypeData, Entities,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], because it
>   implements IDictionary.

I'm pretty sure this why I'm getting a blank page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<add name="Documentation"/>
```

Comment: This should of worked, but it did not. So you made me thing of trying ?wsdl. And I noticed an error. See update for details.

Comment: Yeah, you can't serialize a dictionary.

Comment: It's very weird because all this time I've been getting response with what i'd expect to get from a serialized Dictionary (hash suitable for JSON). So calling this webmethod from jquery has been working fine and it still does. I simply get a blank page for the documentation.